# get standard deviation by group in R

Tags: r

I want to get the standard deviation by group in R (in this case same Genus and Species). However, some of my groups consist of n=1, therefore I cannot calculate the standard deviation.

Here is a random dataset that looks similar to my real dataset

```
x = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Genus1", 
"Genus2", "Genus3"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3"
), class = "factor"), V3 = c(6.32, 8.43, 8.31, 9.29, 8.96)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Desired output something like this? Not sure the best way to handle n=1 groups.

```
    V1        V2             V3
Genus1  Species1    
Genus2  Species2    0.084852814
Genus2  Species2    
Genus3  Species3    0.233345238
Genus3  Species3
```

Comment: Try `x %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(V3 = sd(V3))` or `aggregate(V3 ~ V1, x, sd)`

Comment: akrun solution requires the package 'dplyr'

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```r
aggregate(x$V3, x[,c("V1","V2")], sd)
#       V1       V2          x
# 1 Genus1 Species1         NA
# 2 Genus2 Species2 0.08485281
# 3 Genus3 Species3 0.23334524
```

`data.table` method:

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x)[, .(sigma = sd(V3)), by = .(V1, V2)]
#        V1       V2      sigma
# 1: Genus1 Species1         NA
# 2: Genus2 Species2 0.08485281
# 3: Genus3 Species3 0.23334524
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, we group by 'V1', 'V2' and apply the `sd` on 'V3' to get the standard deviation of 'V3'

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    group_by(V1, V2) %>%
    summarise(V3 = sd(V3))
```